# Adsense reporting API APP_ID is "0:"

Tags: python, admob, adsense-api

I'm trying to get all of my applications' Ids using the adsense management API.
My dimension field is:

`dimension = ['APP_ID', 'APP_NAME']`

In the report I get a lot of rows in the format [ "0:", "some_name", ...metrics... ]

The [documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/reporting) says that applications can have two kinds of IDs according to their platform:

`1:[id] or 2:[id]`

What can be the source of this problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am living same problem. I investigated it. Adsense management api need linked app so if you will linked your app from admob&appstore, You can see APP_ID dimension.

> APP_ID The app store ID or bundle ID of an application. Prefixed with 1: for iOS and 2: for Android. Examples: 1:476954712, 2:com.labpixies.lineup.
>
> APP_NAME   The name of the app. This field is truncated to 80 characters and won't be updated even if the app name changes in the App Store or Google Play store. Examples: Flood-It!, Line Up.
>
> APP_PLATFORM   The app platform. Examples: iOS, Android.

Visit here for more info.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/reporting